# Getting racecheck results faster

Tags: cuda

The documentation for the [racecheck](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-memcheck/index.html#racecheck-report-modes) tool appears old.  (Running cuda-memcheck version 5.0 (17) )
`cuda-memcheck --tool racecheck` doesn't appear to support the analysis report.  `cuda-memcheck --tool racecheck --racecheck-report analysis` tells me there is no racecheck-report option.
In an effort to getting results faster, I'm using: `cuda-memcheck --tool racecheck --show_backtrace no`

The conversion of the memcheck.out binary file to text output is taking too long.  I tried to find a "stop after 50 events" option, but there is none.  Is there a faster approach to running the racecheck tool?

Edit: I could use the --print-level option, but this doesn't help me.  Is there some way to save the binFile.out, and run the bin->txt conversion process later.  Something like: memcheck-convert binFileName txtFileName  (just an idea)

Comment: The documentation you have linked is for the version of `cuda-memcheck` that ships with CUDA 5.5.  There were significant changes to the tool moving from CUDA 5.0 to CUDA 5.5.  I suggest you run with CUDA 5.5 if you want the documentation to match.  Otherwise, use the command line help or the documentation that ships with the CUDA 5.0 toolkit for that version.  With CUDA 5.0, there is a `CUDA_Memcheck.pdf` document that gets installed with the toolkit.  The actual install location is dependent on whether you are using windows or Linux, which you don't mention.

Comment: This looks like it should be an answer, not a comment...

Comment: Version 5.5 runs much faster/better than ver 5.0.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation you have linked is for the version of cuda-memcheck that ships with CUDA 5.5. There were significant changes to the tool moving from CUDA 5.0 to CUDA 5.5. I suggest you run with CUDA 5.5 if you want the documentation to match, and to take advantage of the various improvements.

Otherwise, use the command line help or the documentation that ships with the CUDA 5.0 toolkit for that version. With CUDA 5.0, there is a `CUDA_Memcheck.pdf` document that gets installed with the toolkit. The actual install location is dependent on whether you are using windows or Linux, which you don't mention.